# Need to know how to flip a image c#

Tags: c#

I've got a image in a List. I want it to flip, from the front to the backside. For the backside I've got an other image.

Is this possible? And can you tell me how ?

A piece of my code I've got so far

```
List<Image> GameCards = new List<Image> { Properties.Resources.dj, Properties.Resources.c6, Properties.Resources.sq, Properties.Resources.hq};
try
        {
            Random rgcard1 = new Random();
            int Igcard1 = rgcard1.Next(GameCards.Count);
            Ngcard1 = GameCards[Igcard1];
            GameCards.RemoveAt(Igcard1);

            GCard1.Image = Ngcard1;



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GCard1.Image = Properties.Resources.b1fv;
        }
```

What I mean by flip: https://www.google.nl/search?q=flip&biw=1680&bih=989&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=C_RRVb_fJIbaU-7ZgOgB&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=flip+image&imgrc=FBxks3LN0ZzS_M%253A%3BPk9nUcCgzkVW-M%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fdesandro.github.io%252F3dtransforms%252Fimg%252Fcard-flip01.png%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fdesandro.github.io%252F3dtransforms%252Fdocs%252Fcard-flip.html%3B540%3B186

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "flip, from the front to the backside", do you mean move the item in the list from the first item in the list to the last? As you mentioned it's an image and you want to flip, maybe you mean you want to mirror the display of the image?

Comment: The "flip" you mentioned is just a visual thing done within the UI. This won't change the *value* of the card in any way.

Comment: What i mean by flip: the image i display by GCard1.Image, i want it to turn around. and not rotate horizontal or vertical, but from the front of the image, to the backside of the image. https://www.google.nl/search?q=flip&biw=1680&bih=989&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=C_RRVb_fJIbaU-7ZgOgB&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=flip+image&imgrc=FBxks3LN0ZzS_M%253A%3BPk9nUcCgzkVW-M%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fdesandro.github.io%252F3dtransforms%252Fimg%252Fcard-flip01.png%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fdesandro.github.io%252F3dtransforms%252Fdocs%252Fcard-flip.html%3B540%3B186 < for example

Comment: An image doesn't have a front or a backside. It is your *card* that you like to visualize that has two sides. To do such a thing you normally apply some kind of animation to your picture (by the way is this winforms, wpf, html5?) like shrinking from left to right. When the animation ends (nothing to see anymore) you replace the image and execute the animation backwards.

Comment: Im not sure it is apparent what type of application you are working on here. What front end are you using to display this image? WPF? WinForms? MonoGame? With an idea of this, people might be able to tell you how it can be animated to perform the "flip"

Answer (score 0):

**Not the greatest solution** ...but have you considered using an animated jpg/gif?

you could use a site like this to create it.
[gifmake.com](http://gifmake.com/)